# Правка кода ms sql, генерация схемы

Tags: sql-server

mssql management studio  должна сгенерировать такую схему
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код ms sql

```
CREATE TABLE [DOVIDNUK] (
    Id_room int NOT NULL,
    room_num int NOT NULL,
    Dominotiryroom_num int NOT NULL,
    amoung int NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_DOVIDNUK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  (
  [Id_room] ASC
  ) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)

)
GO
CREATE TABLE [DORMITORIES] (
    Dominotiryroom_num int NOT NULL,
    adress varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Phone_num int NOT NULL,
    Fname_K varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_DORMITORIES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  (
  [Dominotiryroom_num] ASC
  ) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)

)
GO
CREATE TABLE [FACULTIES] (
    faculty_code int NOT NULL,
    Phonenumber_D int NOT NULL,
    Fname_D varchar(55) NOT NULL,
    faculty_name varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_FACULTIES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  (
  [faculty_code] ASC
  ) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)

)
GO
CREATE TABLE [GROUP] (
    group_code int NOT NULL,
    faculty_code int NOT NULL,
    group_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_GROUP] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  (
  [group_code] ASC
  ) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)

)
GO
CREATE TABLE [Personal_card] (
    Card_num int NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    DateBirth date NOT NULL,
    rooms_num int NOT NULL,
    ParentsAdress varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    group_code int NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_PERSONAL_CARD] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  (
  [Card_num] ASC
  ) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)

)
GO
CREATE TABLE [ACCOUNTING] (
    id int NOT NULL,
    Card_num int NOT NULL,
    Id_room int NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_ACCOUNTING] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  (
  [id] ASC
  ) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)

)
GO
ALTER TABLE [DOVIDNUK] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [DOVIDNUK_fk0] FOREIGN KEY ([Id_room]) REFERENCES [ACCOUNTING]([Id_room])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [DOVIDNUK] CHECK CONSTRAINT [DOVIDNUK_fk0]
GO

ALTER TABLE [DORMITORIES] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [DORMITORIES_fk0] FOREIGN KEY ([Dominotiryroom_num]) REFERENCES [DOVIDNUK]([Dominotiryroom_num])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [DORMITORIES] CHECK CONSTRAINT [DORMITORIES_fk0]
GO


ALTER TABLE [GROUP] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [GROUP_fk0] FOREIGN KEY ([faculty_code]) REFERENCES [FACULTIES]([faculty_code])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [GROUP] CHECK CONSTRAINT [GROUP_fk0]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Personal_card] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [Personal_card_fk0] FOREIGN KEY ([Card_num]) REFERENCES [ACCOUNTING]([Card_num])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [Personal_card] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Personal_card_fk0]
GO
ALTER TABLE [Personal_card] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [Personal_card_fk1] FOREIGN KEY ([group_code]) REFERENCES [GROUP]([group_code])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [Personal_card] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Personal_card_fk1]
GO
```

Генерирует такую [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где я сделал не правильно, что у меня таблицы не связаные

Comment: MySQL и MS SQL (он же SQL Server) - это два ну очень разных сервера...

Comment: только начал изучать
у меня ms sql)))

Comment: А сообщения об ошибках посмотреть - не наш метод? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=76571ffd49ce92b83e3ae9dc79160fe5

Comment: метод сгенерировал сайт app.dbdesigner